# Fix key settings (Home/End/Insert/Delete) in .zshrc when running Zsh in Terminator Terminal Emulator

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh, zshrc, terminator

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04. I installed the [Terminator Terminal Emulator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/) 0.95, and Zsh, version 4.3.15. 
I have (commonly known) problems with my keys inside the Zsh. At least these:

- Home/End, nothing happens
- Insert/Delete/PageUp/PageDown: a "~" is typed

I already tried some configurations for .zshrc which should solve the problem, but no approach really worked so far. Maybe this is related to the combination of Terminator and Zsh. I took the 2 configs on this page: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=428669.

Does oneone have a similar configuration (especially Terminator and Zsh) and figured out what needs to be inserted into the .zshrc to fix the key settings?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

To know the code of a key, execute `cat`, press enter, press the key, then Ctrl+C.

For me, `Home` sends `^[[H` and `End` `^[[F`, so i can put i my `.zshrc` in my home dir

```
bindkey  "^[[H"   beginning-of-line
bindkey  "^[[F"   end-of-line
bindkey  "^[[3~"  delete-char
```

These codes could change with the terminal emulator you use.

`autoload zkbd ; zkbd` will create a file with an array of keycodes to use, like `bindkey  "${key[Home]}" beginning-of-line`, and you can source a different file depending on the terminal.

Comment: The cat thing did not work for me, but this [blog post over here](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/08/how-to-get-home-end-keys-working-in.html) shows `od -c`which did the trick for me

Comment: `read` works like `cat` for this. Just remember that `^[` is escape code, `\e` in `.inputrc`.

Comment: I use '^V' followed by desired keystroke. Seems to work anywhere.

Comment: A list of available widgets such as `beginning-of-line` is available [here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Standard-Widgets). For instance, `delete-char` is the widget normally associated with the delete key.

Comment: Have been trying to fix this for an hour and realized that other sollutions didn't work because my keyboard is set to swedish. Your cat trick fixed that, thanks!

Comment: How would one switch out the different keyfiles created by zkbd for different shells, eg. ssh'ing into a box from terminator vs running zsh directly on the machine vs using PuTTY yields different keycodes

Comment: Coming from windows to mac has been so painful and mapping these keys in zshrc worked first shot. Just remember to source ~/.zshrc and then get working

Answer (score 42):

Thanks to @lolesque, but the solution doesn't work with me. After using `zkbd` to check my key binding, I came out the below solution. BTW, my `$TERM` is `xterm`.

```
bindkey  "^[[1~"   beginning-of-line
bindkey  "^[[4~"   end-of-line
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works for me when I am ssh'ed to zsh via hyper.js on windows

Comment: if you read the answer you'll see that he provided the complete solution with `cat` command. And my keys is same as yours. Thank you.

Comment: I found that I have lolesque's bindings in xterm, but yours inside tmux

Answer (score 4):

For me on WSL2 (Windows 10) this was it

```
bindkey "^[OH" beginning-of-line
bindkey "^[OF" end-of-line
```

The `cat` trick did not work for me as it printed `^[[H` as in the accepted answer but I was able to find out the `^[OH` sequence by typing `Ctrl+v Home` in the new Window Terminal running zsh.