# Looking for ALT+LeftArrowKey solution in zsh

Tags: shell, key, zsh

I just recently switched from bash to zsh, however I miss my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrowKey</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrowKey</kbd> to go back and forth a word at a time.

Right now, if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrowKey</kbd> I go back a couple of letters and then I'm stuck. I won't go any further backwards and it won't back to the end of the line with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightArrowKey</kbd> as I would expect. I can't even use the arrow keys to go to the end of the line, only to the second to last. Can't input new chars on the line either or indeed delete.

How do I get my beloved shortcut back?

I'm on Mac OS X using Terminal if that's important.

Answer (score 463, accepted):

Run `cat` then press keys to see the codes your shortcut send.
(Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to kill the `cat` when you're done.)
For me, (ubuntu, konsole, xterm) pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> sends `^[[1;3D`, so i would put in my *.zshrc*

```
bindkey "^[[1;3C" forward-word
bindkey "^[[1;3D" backward-word
```

(Actually I prefer to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + arrow to move word by word, like in a normal textbox under windows or linux gui.)

Related question: [Fix key settings (Home/End/Insert/Delete) in .zshrc when running Zsh in Terminator Terminal Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638012)

Comment: You are my savior! On my Mac "Alt + <-" gave "^[b" and -> gave "^[f", so I added these. Works like a charm. Ctrl+arrows are reserved for switching between desktops on Mac.

Comment: One note is that for ctrl+<- cat was reporting `^[[D` for me while ctrl+v was reporting `^[OD`. Ctrl+v's suggestion worked, but cat's did not. Furthermore, ctrl+v was reporting the same thing for both alt+<- and alt+->. I was able to add these two by looking at cat's output and replacing any "[[" with "O"

Comment: my output under cat is `^[^[[C` for forward word and `^[^[[D` for backward word, but updating for these in .zshrc didn't work for some reason.

Comment: @Yunti - Putting `bindkey "^[^[[D" backward-word` and `bindkey "^[^[[C" forward-word` in *~/.zprofile* worked for me!

Comment: Don't forget to run `source ~/.zshrc` after editing your file

Comment: thanks for your answer. been bugging for a while :)

Comment: The key bindings will work with any shell, including Mac Terminal, iTerm, etc.

Comment: "Run `cat` then press keys to see the codes your shortcut send." best "btw" tip I've seen on SO

Answer (score 330):

**For anyone using iTerm, regardless of shell**

All of the solutions offered here take a backwards approach in my opinion. You're essentially telling your shell to listen for some esc sequence or other key binding you have set in your terminal, creating compatibility issues when you switch shells (If you SSH into some other shell, switch from BASH to ZSH, etc and you lose some if not all of your keybindings).

Most shells have a set of default sequences that come pre-bound. Furthermore, while they aren't 100% consistent, they're close enough. So the easiest way that I have found to create keybinding for a particular action in the shell is to tell your terminal application to bind to the default keybindings that are consistent across shells.

**I wrote a [compressive solution for getting your terminal to respond as close to native mac keybindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205157/iterm2-how-to-get-jump-to-beginning-end-of-line-in-bash-shell/29403520#29403520).**.

[image]

Open the iTerm preferences <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and navigate to the **Profiles** tab (the **Keys** tab can be used, but adding keybinding to your profile allows you to [save your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943676/how-to-export-iterm2-profiles) and sync it to multiple computers) and **keys** sub-tab, click **Key Mappings** and enter the following:

**Move cursor one word left**

> <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> Send Hex Codes: `0x1b 0x62`

**Move cursor one word right**

> <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> Send Hex Codes: `0x1b 0x66`

And that should give you the desired behavior not just in ZSH, but also if you SSH into a server running BASH, irb/pry, node etc.

Comment: I was having trouble with the accepted solution because I had zsh working fine but not irb and other consoles. Erasing previous settings (in iTerm profile as suggested) works like a charm!

Comment: bindkey solution would make annoying error sound on Mac. This should be the right way to do it.

Comment: @Lev Likely because either your shell isn't mapped to the default configuration. Run `bindkey | grep forward-word` you should see `"^[f" forward-word` returned but if you don't, you have 2 options. map to one of the others returned, or add `"^[f" forward-word` to your `.zshrc`.

Comment: I will note, that `"^[f"` seems to be the most consistently used binding for `forward-word` used across shells, and the only one set by default in my version of bash.

Comment: Somehow it worked with command button for me instead of option. Thanks man. :)

Comment: Any reason you recommend to use "Send Hex Codes", rather than "Send Escape Sequence" to send `^[b` and `^[f`, respectively? In iTerm2 I use the latter without an issue.

Comment: And those wondering why that's not the default: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/5451

Comment: This is the correct solution which worked first time for me on a Mac - thank you!

Comment: On the "key mappings" tab you can also load the "Natural Text Editing" preset. This will additionally give you things like alt+backspace for removing a word.

Comment: I selected natural text profile, as described below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70451722/4936193) and it worked like a charm

Comment: The funny thing is that I just added the key to move to the left, which also works for the right. 

Answer (score 93):

Adding the following to ~/.zshrc worked for me on OSX Mountain Lion.

```
bindkey -e
bindkey '[C' forward-word
bindkey '[D' backward-word
```

Comment: This solution triggers a "bell" in iTerm 2 with every use, so jumping between words can get really annoying.

Comment: anyone figure out how to disable this from happening^ @MatthewMorek

Comment: '\e\e' prevents the bell. My configuration on El Capitan with iTerm 2 in Terminal compatibility mode is 

`bindkey "\e\e[D" backward-word`
`bindkey "\e\e[C" forward-word`

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue on macOs Sierra. I don't get any bell sounds on either Terminal or iTerm2.

Comment: How do you set it to move from the end of words and not the start or them?

Comment: Also works on hackintosh ventura with ISO keyboard :D

Answer (score 54):

On MacOS High Siera 10.13.6 or Mojave 10.14.2 and using iTerm2 with ZSH
To move from words I have to put like this:

```
bindkey "\e\e[D" backward-word
bindkey "\e\e[C" forward-word
```

Another solutions doesn't work fo rme

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me as well. Thank you! Mac OS Mojave

Comment: Works on OS Catalina as well!

Comment: \e\e[D.   what keys it represents

Comment: Many thanks, solved the issue for me with Big Sur.

Comment: Works, AND had no 'boop' sound <3

Answer (score 46):

For iTerm, go to where this screenshot shows and select "Natural Text Editing"

[image]

if you already had some key mappings it will ask below, select accordingly not to lose any special bindings you set before. however, if you don't remember adding any bindings or just started using iTerm (on this machine), you will be safe to choose "Remove"

[image]

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer, perfect!

Comment: YES! I'm using iTerm and this worked, thanks!

Comment: This is the best working answer for iTerm!

Comment: Perfect, just do this. No fancy files.

Answer (score 9):

Though not strictly answering your question, the default binding for `forward-word` and `backward-word` are `alt-f` resp. `alt-b`.

This works everywhere, does not require you to leave the home row, and has a nice mnemonic property (f=forward, b=back), while also being consistent with `ctrl-f` and `ctrl-b` being `forward-character` and `backward-character`.

Rip out your arrow keys!

Comment: doesn't work for me in zsh/iterm2, prints  ƒ and ∫ (c-b cf works).

Answer (score 4):

To make it work for me I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31328973/644322), however I had to swap the codes (left <-> right)

⌥+← Send Hex Codes: 0x1b 0x66
⌥+→ Send Hex Codes: 0x1b 0x62

and add the following to my `~/.zshrc`

```
bindkey -e
bindkey "^[b" backward-word
bindkey '^[f' forward-word
```

Comment: It would arguably be less confusing if you changed your `bindkey`s instead, to bind `^[f` to `forward-word`, and not to `backward-word`.

Answer (score 3):

These keybindings work with Alacritty on Arch Linux, just add them to the `~/.zshrc` file

```
bindkey -e

bindkey "^[[3~" delete-char                     # Key Del
bindkey "^[[5~" beginning-of-buffer-or-history  # Key Page Up
bindkey "^[[6~" end-of-buffer-or-history        # Key Page Down
bindkey "^[[H" beginning-of-line                # Key Home
bindkey "^[[F" end-of-line                      # Key End
bindkey "^[[1;3C" forward-word                  # Key Alt + Right
bindkey "^[[1;3D" backward-word                 # Key Alt + Left
```

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS Monterey, use the following in `~/.zshrc` to make `SHIFT` + `Arrows` jump words:

```
bindkey "^[[1;2C" forward-word
bindkey "^[[1;2D" backward-word
```

And this for `Option` + `Arrows`:

```
bindkey "^[^[[C" forward-word
bindkey "^[^[[D" backward-word
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mavericks (10.9.4) the code is 1;5... so for binding alt with arrows I have my .zshrc using this:

```
bindkey "^[[1;5C" forward-word
bindkey "^[[1;5D" backward-word
```

You can use CTRL+V and then the command you want to use

in Yosemite use Rob's solution

Comment: `bindkey "[C" forward-word
bindkey "[D" backward-word`

Answer (score 1):

In zsh, you can use the `bindkey` command to see keyboard shortcuts.

Use `bindkey` to explore options that are available without custom keybindings.

Namely `^[b`  to move backward a word and `^[f` to move forward a word.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iTerm in CSI u mode, the bindings for your `.zshrc` end up being:

```
bindkey '^[[1;3D' backward-word
bindkey '^[[1;3C' forward-word
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want iTerminal to respect Emacs style shortcuts like ^Mf and ^Mb for forward/back a word I found best way to use this tip:

[Making iTerm to translate 'meta-key' in the same way as in other OSes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196357/making-iterm-to-translate-meta-key-in-the-same-way-as-in-other-oses)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is to go to Terminal -> Preferences -> Keyboard and toggle “Use Opt as Meta-key” ON.

It has been that way with Terminal.app for all shells (-that rely on libreadline, I presume) since the beginning of OS X / macOS.

Don’t ask me why Apple never made this the default.