# How to export iTerm2 Profiles

Tags: iterm, iterm2

I needed to reformat my computer and now I'm having trouble copying the settings/profiles over.

I copied the files in `~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm/`

I also copied `~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist` but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Failed to load preferences from custom directory. Falling back to local copy.

Missing or malformed file at "/
com.googlecode.iterm2.plist"
```

---

I also tried saving the profile in a directory so I could send it but it doesn't work.

Here's the location:

iTerm ▶ General ▶ Preferences ▶ Save Settings To Folder

and here's the output:

```
Failed to copy preferences to custom directory. Copy     
/Users/alexcory/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist 
to Alex_Corys_iTerm_Configuration/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist: 
No such process
```

---

The colors work, (found in the path below) but I'm not simply trying to save colors, but rather all my preferences.

iTerm ▶ Preferences ▶ Profiles ▶ Colors ▶ Load Presets ▶ Export

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 553, accepted):

If you have a look at `Preferences -> General` you will notice at the bottom of the panel, there is a setting `Load preferences from a custom folder or URL:`. There is a button next to it `Save settings to Folder`.

So all you need to do is save your settings first and load it after you reinstalled your OS.

If the `Save settings to Folder` is disabled, select a folder (e.g. empty) in the `Load preferences from a custom folder or URL:` text box.

In iTerm2 3.3 the sequence is:
`iTerm2 menu > Preferences > "General" tab > "Preferences" sub-tab`

Comment: Here's the output:
`Failed to copy preferences to custom directory.
Copy /Users/alexcory/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist to Alex_Corys_iTerm_Configuration/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist: No such process`

Comment: I figured it out.  I was just being an idiot.  I was thinking it wanted me to _name_ a file and then choose a directory rather than just choosing a directory to save it in.  I feel so stupid right now...

Comment: Also useful: on 10.9, you have to restart a service, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111534/iterm2-doesnt-read-com-googlecode-iterm2-plist

Comment: How can you export iTerm keybindings?

Comment: A little complement: at very first, the button `Save Current Settings to Folder` is inactive. You have to check `Load preferences from a custom folder or URL:` first and choose a directory(which doesn't need to have an existing preferences file there yet) in order to save the preferences in the future. After that, the button `Save Current Settings to Folder` will become active.

Comment: How can I load the settings after reinstalled my OS?

Comment: @MustafaOlkun after reinstall, launch iTerm2, go Preferences -> General  and click on "Load preferences from a custom folder or URL" (you need to tick the box, then click on Browse and go to the folder that has your preferences, select the folder and click Apply. These preferences will then be imported to your iTerm2.) Note: Arrangements and Keys and Profiles will not be imported.. Go to Preferences->Profiles and click on "Other Actions" and click on "Copy All Profiles as JSON". Save that to a textfile, copy it to the other computer's ~/Library/Application Support/iTerm2/DynamicProfiles .

Comment: yeah @KrzysztofKaczor I am finding this incredibly confusing -- am used to applications offering "save all settings and export them" coupled with "import settings", iTerm2 most certainly does not do that :o

Comment: thanks @esaruoho - this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: And make sure to press `Don't copy` when you set the custom folder.

Comment: @esaruoho Is this still true as of the newest Iterm version? I know I have had issues with this in the past copying over keys so I had to do it manually. It seems it coped over my profiles and keys when I just did it.

Answer (score 93):

It isn't the most obvious workflow. You first have to click `Load preferences from a custom folder or URL`. Select the folder you want them saved in; I keep an appsync folder in Dropbox for these sorts of things. Once you have selected the folder, you can click `Save settings to Folder`. On a new machine / fresh install of your OS, you can now load these settings from the folder. At first I was sure that loading preferences would wipe out my previous settings, but it didn't.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that -- fear of overwriting my extensive profiles and settings tweaks was holding me back from trying that option.

Comment: Added recommendation, **Uncheck Save changes to folder where iTerm2 quits**. Do that manually otherwise your connected machines will be conflicting try to update their window placement settings that don't matter as much.

Comment: How can I load these settings from folder. I couldn't find a way!

Comment: Wow. I absolutely love iTerm2, but this is really problematic. Without stack overflow, I never could have figured this out.

Answer (score 27):

Current version of *iterm2* (*3.4.10*, as of my answer) allows to export the whole profile settings as a json file, which will include everything necessary to rebuild the environment such as colors, fonts, spacing, *Command*, *Working Directory*, keymaps, scrollbars, etc.

To do so:

1. (iTerm2 menu bar) -> **Profiles** -> **Open Profiles...**
2. again, select the profile of interest and press **Edit Profiles...**
3. lower left corner, choose **"Other Actions..."** -> **"Save Profile as Json..."**

To re-import the profile there's **"Import Json Profiles..."**.

Comment: Note: the "main menu" refers to the top bar on OSX, not any of the menus under "Preferences". You can also open the "Profiles" view via CMD + O by default.

Answer (score 26):

I didn't touch the "save to a folder" option. I just copied the two files/directories you mentioned in your question to the new machine, then ran `defaults read com.googlecode.iterm2`.

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/111559

Answer (score 13):

There is another way to do this.

From iTerm2 2.9.20140923 you can use **Dynamic Profiles** as stated in the [documentation page](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-dynamic-profiles.html):

> Dynamic Profiles is a feature that allows you to store your profiles in a file outside the usual macOS preferences database. Profiles may be changed at runtime by editing one or more plist files (formatted as JSON, XML, or in binary). Changes are picked up immediately.

So it is possible to create a file like this one:

```
    {
        "Profiles": [{
                "Name": "MYSERVER1",
                "Guid": "MYSERVER1",
                "Custom Command": "Yes",
                "Command": "ssh root@555.66.77.88",
                "Shortcut": "M",
                "Tags": [
                    "LOCAL", "THATCOMPANY", "WORK", "NOCLOUD"
                ],
                "Badge Text": "SRV1",
            },
            {
                "Name": "MYOCEANSERVER1",
                "Guid": "MYOCEANSERVER1",
                "Custom Command": "Yes",
                "Command": "ssh root@111.222.333.444",
                "Shortcut": "O",
                "Tags": [
                    "THATCOMPANY", "WORK", "DIGITALOCEAN"
                ],
                "Badge Text": "PPOCEAN1",
            },
            {
                "Name": "PI1",
                "Guid": "PI1",
                "Custom Command": "Yes",
                "Command": "ssh root@555.66.77.99",
                "Shortcut": "1",
                "Tags": [
                    "LOCAL", "PERSONAL", "RASPBERRY", "SMALL"
                ],
                "Badge Text": "LocalServer",
            },
            {
                "Name": "VUZERO",
                "Guid": "VUZERO",
                "Custom Command": "Yes",
                "Command": "ssh root@777.555.44.66",
                "Shortcut": "0",
                "Tags": [
                    "LOCAL", "PERSONAL", "SMALL"
                ],
                "Badge Text": "TeleVision",
            }
        ]
    }
```

in the folder `~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2/DynamicProfiles/` and share it across different machines.
This enables you to retain some visual differences among iterm2 installations such as font type or dimension, while synchronising remote hosts, shortcuts, commands, and even a small badge to quickly identify a session

[image: badge]

Comment: One issue, this does not retain Keys or Arrangements. Still looking for how to retain those. I can't believe iTerm2 have made this so difficult. What, 3 or more files need to be created, as opposed to "Save Preferences"?? :o

Answer (score 7):

Reading the iTerm2 settings from the folder can be problematic, so I suggest the URL method.

To export the **.plist** file:

1. `iTerm2 -> Preferences -> General`.
2. `Preferences tab > Load Preferences from a custom folder or a URL:` > choose a folder and click on `Save Now`
3. Go to [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/), upload the file, and ensure it's a public gist.
4. Click on `raw` to see only the content and copy the URL. (e.g., https://gist.githubusercontent.com/name/t76...)

To import this file on new machine, it's the same steps as above:

1. `iTerm2 -> Preferences -> General`.
2. `Preferences tab > Load Preferences from a custom folder or a URL: > input the link`
3. Wait for 5-10 seconds, and close & open iTerm2 again.
4. All settings are now imported.

Answer (score 6):

**Caveats: this answer only allows exports color settings.**

iTerm => Preferences => Profiles => Colors => Load Presets => Export

Import shall be similar.

Comment: And it shouldn't be geeky at all but was hard to find anyways. The question stated "profiles" and colors are only one aspect, yes, but I think most people just need the colors.

Comment: This only exports the colors. I have a ton of other config and I assume many people have too (such as terminal size, shortcuts) so it is not a very good answer.

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan what's a better answer? I'll change the actual answer if this isn't the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Preferences -> General -> Load preferences from a custom folder or URL`

First time you choose this, it will automatically save a preferences file into a folder named `com.googlecode.iterm2.plist`