# How do I import an iTerm2 profile?

Tags: macos, configuration, configuration-files, iterm2

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23356086/332936) helped me with how to *export* a profile configuration file, but how do I ***import*** that file into iterm2 on my new machine?

(the file I exported was called `com.googlecode.iterm2.plist`, for what it's worth)

Comment: would be nice if there was an applescript to do this :(

Answer (score 29):

just upload your `*.plist` to `~/Library/Preferences`.
 Notice, that checkbox:

```
Load preferences from a custom folder or URL
```

in `Preferences - General` (at the bottom) must be disabled.

Comment: This answer is the one and only. Thanks dude

Answer (score 12):

1. **First export all the profiles from iTerm2 as below:**

   - Go to Profiles
   - Open Profiles
   - Edit Profiles
   - Other actions
   - Copy All Profiles as JSON
   - Save it to some place you will remember
2. **How to import from above JSON file format which is actually a plist format:**

   - go to your home directory  cd ~
   - cd Library/Application Support/iTerm2/DynamicProfiles
   - copy your json file you saves to this DynamicProfiles folder
   - cp {backuppath-where-you-exported-in-step1}/itermprofiles.json .
3. Restart iTerm2 now in profiles it should show all your old profiles

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But after all this, when I changed something in the loaded dynamic profile, the change is lost when I reload iTerm. The solution was to duplicate the loaded dynamic profile in `Preferences > Profiles` and set that one as default.

Comment: Step 2 is described confusingly. Are you saying that, to import iTerm2 profiles from JSON, one should save the json as a file located at `~/Library/Application Support/iTerm2/DynamicProfiles/itermprofiles.json`?

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I import iTerm (iTerm2) JSON Profile files

Open iTerm and Select `Profiles` from menu
[image]

Select `Edit Profiles` button
[image]

Select `Other Actions...` button.
Then select "Import JSON Profiles...'
And then navigate Finder and select the profile you want to import
[image]

Comment: this is the correct answer.

Comment: echo this, thanks @Mike Barlow

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple utility that creates iTerm2 json profiles from list of servers here : [iTerm2profiles](https://github.com/devsead/iTerm2profiles)

Answer (score 0):

Just export the JSON file for all the profiles and then Import as shown above the page. This works fine for me. It saves a lot of time, as I've many profiles for web servers.