# How do I import a .terminal profile in Iterm2?

Tags: macos, iterm2, iterm

If I have a .terminal profile - created with the default Terminal app for Mac - how do I import it in Iterm2 ?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211565/how-do-i-import-an-iterm2-profile) it might be of help

Comment: @petrubear That answer describes how to import iTerm profiles, not Terminal profiles.

Comment: Did iTerm2 switch from XML (`.terminal`) profiles to JSON in some version? I'm really confused about the other answer also taking about `.plist` (XML) and such.