# PhpStorm zsh terminal CTRL+(leftArrowKey or rightArrowKey) not working

Tags: terminal, phpstorm, zsh

On phpstorm terminal window (with zsh shell) when I do a CTRL+(leftArrowKey or rightArrowKey) what is happening is this:

[Navigation behavior error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN5EK.gif)

Searched the problem in other terminal emulators and found this solution:

Searched solution -> [Looking for ALT+LeftArrowKey solution in zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382499/looking-for-altleftarrowkey-solution-in-zsh)

So I've done what user lolesque said to do:

[Tried lolesque solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS5Ja.gif)
and added to my ~/.zshrc file these lines:

```
bindkey -e
bindkey "^[[5C" forward-word
bindkey "^[[5D" backward-word
```

The problem is that the solution found does not work :|.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, currently these bindings are only supported for Bash.
Please vote here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180154

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey "\e\eOD" backward-word 
bindkey "\e\eOC" forward-word
```

Don't forget to restart the terminal or to

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

for applying the changes.

Source: https://gist.github.com/ecksite/e341835ef266e67b63a2620aee692fdd